# Logout from backend in Spring Boot with Spring Secutiry

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am developing a user management system with Spring Boot and Spring Boot Security. However, I face the problem that if a user is deleted by the administrator while the user is logged in, its session remains giving Server Internal errors. That is why I need to de-authenticate, or logout this user at the moment it is deleted. What are some possible solutions?

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: If you're using Spring Session, you could simply straight-up invalidate all of the user's sessions in your logic that removes the user. Note, however, that it's usually best to disable the user rather than actually delete the database record.

Comment: I think I have asked my question incorrectly. I am not using Spring Session, I am using Spring Boot with Spring Boot Security. Thank you for the remark!!!

Comment: Then depending on your deployment model, maybe you *should* use Spring Session. Makes life a lot easier!

Comment: if you depend on external session, you should check it per each request. If it's already invalid - logout that user.

Comment: or, in entity based mapping, you can map all your session to user via list and make it Cascade.delete. Then, logout user if his session is null

Comment: Ok, but what class or interface can do that things? My problem is that I do know how to access the sessions.